# house power off but wires still hot

Tags: wiring

I'm trying to change a light fixture that's on a switch loop. It's the craziest thing, but I can't find the circuit for the switch loop wires. I tried cutting every single circuit, then I cut power to the whole house. The switch loop wires are still hot even though the wires in the box from the panel (as well as the whole rest of the house) are dead. I know they're hot because a) my voltage meter says so and b) I got shocked. How can this be?

Comment: Uh oh.  Are you certain you only have that one panel?

Comment: Is this multi-unit?  Duplex, apt, etc?  Or is it single family residence?

Comment: There's a new panel in the detached garage. Should I cut that too?

Comment: It's a single family residence. Craftsman bungalow built in 1906 with a detached garage added about 10 years ago. I just purchased the place so I don't know the whole history.

Comment: So I just cut the power to the house AND garage panels. Same situation: everything is dead except for the two switch-loop wires. Wtf?

Comment: First check that it's not powered through the added panel. If there's still power, this could be due to a serious wiring error or even  someone's attempt to bypass the power meter. That *definitely* need to be fixed!

Comment: Can you tell where the cables from the power company enter your house? They should go right to a fuse box.

Comment: Yes, you have to find the service drop or service lateral to the meter, then follow the fat conduit or wire to the **first** service panel.   Also be aware there is something called a "Rule of Six" panel where you must shut off all the breakes in the (typically top) 6 double spaces.